# Illustrating Normal Approximation to Binomial (CLT)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, sampling, central-limit-theorem

For a sampling distribution of sample proportion problem (Bernoulli distribution - $\mathbb P(\mathrm{yellow ball}) = 0.6$ out of $10000$ balls, say), I get below discrete distribution (LHS) with $\mu=0.6$ and $\sigma=0.15$. When I try to draw equivalent normal pdf, its scaled up way above. However, when I scale up discrete distribution by sample size (of $10$), both pdf and discrete distribution matches. So far I could not find any glitch in code that could produce this. Is this a proper expected output? How do we justify? Does this mean we have an inherent limitation in applying normal approximation? Kindly explain.

[image]

I see that, once $\sigma$ is below $0.4$, the constant part in normal function is above $1$, so no more fit for an approximation when we have discrete dist with $\sigma \leq 0.4$? Sample size $n$ is $10$. If $np$ is at play it only worsens when I increase sample size $n$, reducing the $\sigma$.

If you doubt it still should be a glitch in code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732594/sampling-distribution-normal-approximation-misfit) is with code.

Comment: This is sampling distribution $\hat{X}(0.6,0.15)$ of initial Bernoulli distribution $Y(0.6,0.4898)$ , so the resulting SD is supposed to be $\sigma_\hat{X} = \dfrac {\sigma_y}{\sqrt{n}}$.  $\frac {0.4898}{\sqrt{10}} = 0.15$. For my detailed approach kindly check code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732594/sampling-distribution-normal-approximation-misfit?noredirect=1#comment90427241_51732594). Totally stuck :(

Answer (score 1):

If you take a sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ of size $n$ of independent and identically distributed observations from a Bernoulli distribution with probability parameter $p$, and compute the sample proportion $$\hat p = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i,$$ then $\hat p$ is approximately normal with mean $\mu = p$ and variance $\sigma^2 = p(1-p)/n$.  When creating a histogram of $N$ simulations of $\hat p$, you would compute the **density** of observed proportions; i.e., for each $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$, you would compute the number $s_k$ of simulations for which $\hat p = k/n$, then plot a scaled histogram comprising the vertical bars $$\left\{\left(\frac{k}{n}, \frac{n s_k}{N}\right)\right\}_{k=0}^n.$$

When done in this fashion, the resulting histogram will overlay with a normal distribution with the aforementioned mean and variance.  Note that the height of the bar is $n s_k/N$, not $s_k/N$.  This is where your error lies.  The reason is because the height of the bar is not a probability, but a probability **density**--this should become obvious once you realize that when $\sigma$ is sufficiently small for a normal distribution (how small exactly?), then there will be some value for which the corresponding density will exceed $1$.

Plotting in *Mathematica*:

```
G[n_, nn_, p_] := Show[ListPlot[#/{1, nn/n} & /@ 
   Sort[Tally[RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[n, p], nn]/n]], 
   Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}, AspectRatio -> 1], 
   Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[p, Sqrt[p (1 - p)/n]], x], {x, 0, 1},
   PlotRange -> All]]

G[10, 10000, 0.6]
```

I make no claims as to the efficiency of the code.

Comment: Great help, thank you very much, and I will explore and revert.  The values $\frac {k}{n}$ and $\frac{ns_k}{N}$ represent width and height of the bars? So when $\sigma \leq 0.4$, the continuous density and discrete probability distribution do not match up? I wanted to show discrete probability distribution matching up with continuous density function, but counter intuitively, that means my sample size should be lesser? (so SD increases big enough to reduce max of density function?)

Comment: No; $k/n$ is the horizontal position of the bar, and $ns_k/N$ is the height.  What I wrote above has nothing to do with $\sigma \le 0.4$, which is a value that you empirically found.  It just so happens that when $n = 10$ and $p = 0.6$, $\sigma < 1/\sqrt{2\pi}$.  What you should have understood from my answer is that **you cannot get the discrete mass to match the density**.  The former must correspond to heights that add to $1$.  The latter does not because the total area under the density integrates to $1$.

Comment: Kindly forgive my slowness, I find difficulty grasping. Bigger picture is I have been trying to understand sample distributions of sample proportion(SDSP) and sample distributions of sample mean (SDSM)., the above attempt is for the latter. For SDSP it was possible for me to show discrete approx prob but now am doubtful how far am correct. If possible, can you kindly have a glance [here](https://bit.ly/2OWzPsS) (just a one page document of 3 cases) and check if am conceptually ok? I could create another SE question for that if its permitted.  Its not assignment but just notes of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to approximate the distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n = 10, p = .6),$ using $m = 10,000$ iterations. That distribution has mean $\mu = np = 10(.6) = 6,$ variance $\sigma^2 = np(1-p) = 2.4,$ and standard deviation $\sigma = \sqrt{2.4} = 1.5492.$
Then you want to to compare a histogram of the simulation results results with the approximating normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma.$

If you want someone to critique your Python code, you should ask on a programming site. But I will do a similar simulation using R, and discuss how to make
the histogram (nearly) match the normal density function. That part involves
basic ideas of statistics and probability.

```
set.seed(1888);  m = 10000;  n = 10;  p = .6;  mu = 6;  sg=sqrt(2.4)
x = rbinom(m, n, p)      # simulate binomial realizations
cutp=(-1:10)+.5          # cutpoints for histogram
hdr = "Random Sample from BINOM(10,.6) with Normal Approx."
hist(x, br=cutp, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg), -1, 11, add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
 xx = 0:10; pdf.binom = dbinom(xx, n, p)
 points(xx, pdf.binom, pch=19)
```

[image]

In order to coordinate a histogram with a density curve, you need to realize
that the fundamental principle of a histogram is *area.* In R, the parameter
`prob=T` of the function `hist` makes a histogram whose bars have area
summing to $1.$ I have chosen cutpoints for the histgram to be exactly $1$
unit apart; thus bars have bases of width one unit and the heights will
turn out to be approximations of probabilities in the binomial distribution.

```
diff(pnorm(c(6.5, 7.5), mu, sg))
[1] 0.206982
dbinom(7, n, p)
[1] 0.2149908
```

Thus, when I plot the normal density curve (with area $1$ underneath), it will
appear to run nearly through the tops of the histogram bars. I'm saying "nearly"
here because ten thousand iterations isn't enough to approximate the binomial
distribution *exactly* --within the resolution of the figure.

Also, the area under the normal curve between 6.5 and 7.5 is 0.2070, and the
binomial probability $P(X = 7) = 0.2150.$ Ordinarily, you can expect about
two decimal place accuracy from a normal approximation to a binomial distribution.
However, that only works for sufficiently large $n$ and $p$ sufficiently close
to $1/2.$ (A common rule of thumb is that both $np$ and $n(1-p)$ must exceed $5,$
not quite achieved here.)

Finally, I plotted *exact* normal probabilities (black dots) to make it
possible to assess how well the simulation performed, approximating the binomial PDF.

Comment: Thank you Bruce for detailed answer with R snippet. Bigger picture of my attempt is trying to simulate, visualize and understand "Sampling distribution of Sample Proportion" and "Sampling distribution of Sample Means". With same gumball example, it looks like you have taken "Sampling distribution of Sample Means" route because you end up with mean 6, but I should be getting $\hat{p}$ approximating to real bernoulli population $p$ which is 0.6? With same gumball example, when one becomes question of sample proportion or sample means?

Comment: Feel free to ask further closely related questions here, or to post any of your results that you think may be doubtful in a new Question. // Many related questions have solid theoretical answers based on Central Limit Theorem and estimation theory.

Comment: yes, I try to visualize and convince myself if these work instead of taking at face value. What intrigues now is that,  [here](https://bit.ly/2OWzPsS) in my attempt to understand Sample means,where I worked out 3 cases, and in all, I did not have to adjust discrete probability distribution to fit continuous normal approx. So I am now doubtful how far am I correct there. Can you kindly review [that](https://bit.ly/2OWzPsS). Its just a page of 3 cases, I wrote for my understanding.  I could create another post for that if needed and permitted or can update here accordingly. Kindly let me know.

Comment: Took a quick look. A few comments: Should make it clear that Binom(n, p) is sum of n indep Bernoulli's each with success probability p. // Lower left panel of fig just before Sect 4 can't be correct. // You use too many 'hats' (e.g. $\hat X$); need a better way to distinguish btw a random variable and a realization of it. Customary to use hats on symbols for parameters to indicate a parameter estimate: $\hat \mu$ estimate of $\mu.$ // Really like the dynamic figures with control bars.// Should not rely _entirely_ on computer simulation for illustrations. Try to find simple real-world examples.

Comment: great, thank you for review, so overall conceptually they are ok?  all hats indicate they a re outcome of statistical attempt. Only 2 statistical RVs through out. $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$, although $\hat{Y}$ is not direct statistical but inference from $\hat{X}$ and wanted to differentiate from real underlying RV $Y$. I wanted to show the machinery generating the plots, so there is a connect between what is stated and what we see which I find lacking in many tutorials. Can you kindly elaborate on fig before sec 4? Could not understand y they could be wrong.

Comment: Only lower left panel is in question. Suggest different font for computer simulated quantities, maybe just lower case, may script. Also I have seen stars $X^*$ (especially in bootstrapping).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81379/discussion-between-paari-vendhan-and-bruceet).

Comment: Sorry. Too late here. Need to sign off for now.

Comment: Sure, I highly appreciate your time for reviewing it. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple graphical reason why the graphs sometimes do not line up:
you are graphing two completely different things.

For the plot of the normal density, which is from a continuous distribution,
the *total area* under the curve should be $1.$

But for the plot of a discrete density, the *sum of the lengths* of the bars should be $1.$

If every bar were one unit wide, then the total length of the bars would also be their total area. You can do this easily in the plot for your second distribution (the one with $\mu \approx 6$), because the bars are spaced $1$ unit apart. If you widen the bars so they are all one unit wide, each bar will just touch the ones on either side of it, and the total area of the bars will be equal to the sum of their lengths.

Try scaling up the distribution by yet another factor of $10$ so that the discrete outcomes are $0, 10, 20, \ldots, 100.$
I think you will find then that the discrete graph and the normal approximation are mismatched in height again, but this time the bars will be much higher than the curve.

In summary, you have one plot based on *length* and another based on *area.*
These two plots will only line up when you have adjusted the width of the graph so that "length" just happens to coincide with "area."
For any other width of the graph, you will get a mismatch between the heights of the bars and the height of the curve.

---

One way to do a normal approximation of a discrete distribution, 
by the way, is to divide the normal distribution into sections and assign each section to one of the discrete values. If you do this correctly, you will have *two* bar graphs, which can then be compared directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. Yes I understand that discrete bars have to have  height adjusted and with width, so when the total of their area becomes 1, automatically they will line up with continuous density, but when I do that, I can no more  call them a discrete probability distribution right? In many tutorials, they say discrete probability distribution could be approximated to normal with sufficiently large n, so I wanted to visually show (at same time, not having to change graph because then its no more discrete probability distribution.

Comment: This insight also makes me doubt my earlier understanding with which I wrote detailed notes [here](https://bit.ly/2OWzPsS) about 3 sampling cases, where without having to do this adjustment, my disc.prob.dist automatically lined up with continuous. Can you kindly check that [here](https://bit.ly/2OWzPsS) and let me know if I am conceptually correct there still? It is just 3 probability cases., for which I did not adjust height or width, and still they lined up caz $\sigma \geq$ certain value?

Comment: The width of the bar is just a graphical device. It does not change the meaning of the graph. Your earlier graphs all line up because, again, the discrete values are all $1$ unit apart.