# Why Sampling distribution not skewed when np < 10 and nq < 10?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, sampling, python

My aim is to study "Sample distributions" via simulations convincing myself of the outcomes.

After struggling with questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878417/how-sample-mean-equals-population-mean/2879037?noredirect=1#comment5944891_2879037), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877525/sampling-distribution-disturbing-answer/2877575?noredirect=1#comment5942513_2877575) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875762/illustrating-normal-approximation-to-binomial-clt/2876664?noredirect=1#comment5939365_2876664), finally I hope am somewhat getting my head around it.

I tried to simulate a population of bernoulli random variable Y, with a given probability for Y=1. I tried to sample from it, each time sample size being 'n', for 'N' experiments. The sampling distribution turned out to be normal as expected.

I tried to then show, the problem would not be a good fit for normal approximation, when np < 10 or nq < 10 because the distribution would be skewed.  But when I simulate in python, I do not observe much skewness. The "extreme" curves were as good as some of intermediate curves, so I do not get it.

I tried increasing sample size, no of experiments, but no improvement. 
I tried using **bar** instead of **hist**, but in vain. I tried varying width of them but no use (in fact changing width affects size for another purpose - to maintain total height as 1 due to density=True)

Kindly check and let me know if there is any issue in the math I am doing.

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from SDSPSM import create_bernoulli_population, sample_for_SDSP
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt, pi

# control inputs
T = 10000
p_list = np.arange(0.1,1,0.1)  # varying probability

N = 2000  # no of experiments
n = 50    # sample size


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(12,4))
plt.close()


def animate(i): 

    ax.clear()

    p = round(p_list[i],4)

    # create  population to be sampled from - Note pop has to be re created every time due to changing p
    pops = create_bernoulli_population(T, p)    

    _, Y_mean_list = sample_for_SDSP(pops, N,n)

    # plot discrete density
    _, bins,_ = ax.hist(Y_mean_list, density=True)

    # normal approx
    mu, var, sigma = get_metrics(Y_mean_list)

    X = np.linspace(min(bins),max(bins),10*len(bins))
    if sigma>0:
        Cp = 1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))
        Ep = -1/2*((X-mu)/sigma)**2
        G = Cp*np.exp(Ep)    
        ax.plot(X, G, color='red')         
    metrics_text = '$\mu_x:{}$ \n$\sigma_x:{}$'.format(mu, sigma)
    ax.text(0.97, 0.98,metrics_text,ha='right', va='top',transform = ax.transAxes,fontsize=10,color='red')    


    ax.set_ylim([0,15])
    ax.set_xlim([0,1])

    np_factor = round(n*p,2)
    nq_factor = round(n*(1-p),2)
    metrics_text_2 = '$p:{}$ \n$np:{}$ \n$nq:{}$'.format(p, np_factor, nq_factor)
    ax.text(0.01, 0.98,metrics_text_2,ha='left', va='top',transform = ax.transAxes,fontsize=10,color='red')    

plt.show()

ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = range(0,len(p_list)), interval=1000)

from IPython.display import HTML
def display_animation(anim):
    plt.close(anim._fig)
    return HTML(anim.to_html5_video())

display_animation(ani1)
```

Helper file: [SDSPSM](https://gist.github.com/parthi2929/0c99cf799faf8d63c5c863ba4165500e)

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: "when np < 10 or nq < 10 because the distribution would be skewed" No it would not (be skewed). What makes you think it would be?

Comment: khan academy: https://youtu.be/L7AX2RcbqCg. They said thumb rule, but I wanted to verify and convince myself

Comment: And their diagrams simply allude to the fact that the mode of the binomial distribution Bin$(n,p)$ is located at $k<\frac n2$ if $p<\frac12$ and at $k>\frac n2$ if $p>\frac12$. For every $(n,p)$, the mode is located exactly at $k=\lfloor np-1+p\rfloor$, thus, roughly at $np$. Thus, sorry but you misread this hugely.

Comment: jbstatistics proves the skewness here: https://youtu.be/fuGwbG9_W1c

Comment: I could have probably proved easier, if my population distribution was binomial in first place (so sampling distribution is easily normal), but I wanted to take general case (bernoulli, which is least binomial for sampling distribution, and random distribution for sample means) to prove the issue if the conditions are not met.

Comment: Again, no. Please read a definition of skewness.

Comment: what do we call this then? [1](https://s15.postimg.cc/pvtkb6mzv/image.png) at [6:52](https://youtu.be/fuGwbG9_W1c?t=412) and  [2](https://s15.postimg.cc/49ejua6gr/2018-08-13_12h19_42.png) at [8:12](https://youtu.be/fuGwbG9_W1c?t=492). I am interested in getting that effect to prove.

Comment: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) says "In probability theory and statistics, skewness is a measure of the asymmetry of the probability distribution of a real-valued random variable about its mean". I am looking for that asymmetry like shown in above videos, khan and jbstatistics.

Comment: Yes but the figures Khan Academy provide to demonstrate asymmetry are misleading. Let me repeat: for every $(n,p)$, the mode is roughly at $np$, as it should be.

Comment: you could ignore khan, and find fault in mine why it does not produce skewness like in jbstatistics?

Comment: Again, what you are lacking at present is a solid definition of skewness... Once you will have this in your bag, my guess is that all your question should be solved.

Comment: Do you mean, you should not observe skewness because for every (n,p), mode is also the mean? (if so, its symmetric) no matter what the value of p is?. Did you take in to consideration this is random sampling distribution, not population distribution?